# Why my modal is not working and not showing up, I want to send it to code behind

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

My modal is not working. Actually I want a modal for sign up and send it to my code behind page. I have used bootstrap lumen and jquery. Please help me, any help would be beneficial. Thanks in advance.

Also I need to make a form and generate ajax call for that.

[image: screenshot]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="HotelReservation.Views.Login" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="../css/custom1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form_bg">
                <form>
                    <h2 class="text-center">Login Page</h2>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="userid" placeholder="User id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="align-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="login">Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Launch Modal </button>
                    <div class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" id="mymodal">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="HotelReservation.Views.Login" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="../css/custom1.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form_bg">
              <form>
                <h2 class="text-center">Login Page</h2>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="userid"
                    placeholder="User id"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="pwd"
                    placeholder="Password"
                  />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="align-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="login">
                    Login
                  </button>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div
                  class="btn btn-success"
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#mymodal"
                >
                  Launch Modal
                </div>
                <div class="modal">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" id="mymodal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          class="close"
                          data-dismiss="modal"
                          aria-label="Close"
                        >
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                          Save changes
                        </button>
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          class="btn btn-secondary"
                          data-dismiss="modal"
                        >
                          Close
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".btn-success").click(function() {
              console.log("hit");
              $(".modal").modal("show");
            });
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your jquery script needs to come before bootstrap.js

Comment: Now whats happening is a black screen is appering but i cant see the modal

Comment: Your welcome please mark my answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

add this script in head section

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          function ShowPopup() {

              $("#btnShowPopup").click();
          }
    </script>
```

Now add this code in body

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="btnShowPopup" style="display:none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  CssClass="btn btn-success" style="padding:5px;font-size:14px;" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="View Contact" />
 <div id="myModal"  class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:#00ca4c;">Lead Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-md-12">


          </div>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="padding-right:15px;">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

and add this in your code behind

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {

      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
}
```

in the button click event on which you want to open modal